# Get elapsed time from SQL Server for notification system

Tags: sql-server, date

I have a date in SQL Server from a view... I want to know how many minutes, days, months, years have passed between the date from SQL Server and the current date.

If minutes are less than 2 it should give me "Just Now", if not it should give me "3 Minutes" also if a day has passed should say "1 day ago" something like that..

Thanks !

Comment: Do some research on DATEDIFF

Comment: Go through this: [DATEDIFF()](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/datediff.php)

Comment: After you learn DATEDIFF, learn CASE statements.